# No magnetic field in the case of oscillating electric charges - proof

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, astrophysics, plasma-physics

I am reading the book Plasma dynamics by Dendy (2002) and I stumbled at a derivation of a proof.

I do not quite understand why equation $1.23$ is equal to zero. Also, equation **I.**$9$ is $\nabla\times\mathbf{H}=\mathbf{J}+\epsilon_0\frac{\partial\mathbf{E}}{\partial t}$.

I would appreciate any help/hint. Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we linearize the equations, we make the assumption that all quantities can be written as:
$$
Q\left( \mathbf{x}, t \right) = Q_{o} + \delta Q
$$
where $Q_{o}$ is constant and $\delta Q \propto e^{i \left( \mathbf{k} \cdot \mathbf{x} - \omega \ t \right)}$.  This means that operators can be replaced in the following way:
$$
\begin{align}
  \nabla & = i \ \mathbf{k} \\
  \partial/\partial t & = -i \ \omega
\end{align}
$$
In the case of an electrostatic wave like the Langmuir oscillations to which you refer, the particles oscillate along the quasi-static magnetic field.  The wave itself is a [longitudinal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longitudinal_wave) osciallation, i.e., the wavevector is aligned with electric field oscillations.

So if we look at [Faraday's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday%27s_law_of_induction), and we use the linear approximation above knowing that $\mathbf{k} \ \parallel \ \delta \mathbf{E}$ (i.e., the cross product of two parallel vectors is null) we find that:
$$
\begin{align}
  \nabla \times \mathbf{E} & = -\frac{\partial \mathbf{B}}{\partial t} \\
  \mathbf{k} \times \delta \mathbf{E} & = -i \ \omega \ \delta \mathbf{B} \\
  & = 0
\end{align}
$$

Thus, if we take the partial time derivative of [Ampere's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amp%C3%A8re%27s_circuital_law) (i.e., Equation 1.22 in your image), we find:
$$
\begin{align}
  \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \left( \nabla \times \mathbf{B} \right) & = \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \left( \mu_{o} \mathbf{j} + \frac{1}{c^{2}} \frac{\partial \mathbf{E}}{\partial t} \right) \\
  \nabla \times \frac{\partial \mathbf{B}}{\partial t} & = \mu_{o} \frac{\partial \mathbf{j}}{\partial t} + \frac{1}{c^{2}} \frac{\partial^{2} \mathbf{E}}{\partial t^{2}} \\
  0 & = \mu_{o} \frac{\partial \mathbf{j}}{\partial t} + \frac{1}{c^{2}} \frac{\partial^{2} \mathbf{E}}{\partial t^{2}}
\end{align}
$$
which is precisely what is shown in your Equation 1.23.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand your question...

Assuming that equation 1.23 is correct, and that the electric field is of the form $$E = E_0 e^{i\omega t}$$

(namely, "oscillating" with simple harmonic motion), then the second derivative with respect to time exactly cancels the $\omega^2 E$ term... and thus it's zero.

Is that what you were asking?

Comment: This is true only if $\omega=\omega_{\textrm{pc}}$. I think he might be asking why this equality is true. I think the reason is because the electric field is arising only due to the [plasma oscillations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plasma_oscillation) of the electrons which occur only at the [plasma frequency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plasma_oscillation#.27Cold.27_electrons) $\omega_{pc}=\sqrt{\dfrac{n_0 e^2}{\epsilon_0 m}}$. In principle you could impose an electric field of arbitrary frequency and then you would not get this cancelation, and so a magnetic field would result.

Comment: @NowIGetToLearnWhatAHeadIs - your comment may well be the piece that was missing in OP's understanding...

Comment: I think the part that is missing is that for an electrostatic wave, $\partial \mathbf{B}/\partial t = 0$ (i.e., Faraday's law reduces to $\mathbf{k} \times \mathbf{E} = 0$).  This is why Eq. 1.23 goes to zero, not that $\omega = \omega_{pe}$.  At least, I think that's what it is meant here.